# Eigenvalues of matrix satisfying squared equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to find eigenvalues of a matrix satisfying the following equation:
\begin{align}
\notag
A^{2}x=\frac{1}{2}Ax + 2x,
\end{align}
by solving the equation $2\lambda^{2} - \lambda - 4 = 0$?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda$ must satisfy the polynomial equation you wrote down, i.e., the polynomial equation is necessary. (To prove this, suppose that $X$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, so $AX = \lambda X$, and plug this into your matrix equation; what will pop out is your polynomial equation.) The question is whether the polynomial equation is sufficient.

Comment: From the Cayley Hamilton Theorem, the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$ will satisfy its own characteristic equation, $det (A - \lambda I) = 0 = \lambda^2 -(a+d) \lambda + (ad-bc) = 0$. So a matrix with $a, b, c, d$ *s.t.* $a + d = -1/2, ad - bc = -2$ then $A$ will satisfy $A^2 - \frac{1}{2} A - 2I = 0$. Is this what you want? It isn't clear if $X$ is meant to be an eigenvector or some general vector.

Comment: Yes, in my case X is a general vector that belongs to a space of vectors that satisfy the matrix equation I wrote. I need eigenvalues of A in order to write the space of vectors X as a direct sum of the corresponding eigenspaces.

Comment: In the future, use lower case letters for vectors. Upper case are usually reserved for matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the roots of the polynomial $\lambda^2-\frac{1}{2}\lambda-2$ are in the field where you are working so that
$$
     \lambda^2-\frac{1}{2}\lambda-2=(\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2),
$$
then
$$
             (A-\lambda_1 I)(A-\lambda_2 I)X = 0.
$$
Assume $X\ne 0$. Either $AX=\lambda_2 X$ or $AY=\lambda_1 Y$ where $Y=(A-\lambda_2I)X\ne 0$. So, either $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$ is an eigenvalue, assuming $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ are in your field.